# How to catch or override the "onCellLocationChanged(): got cell location that isn't gsm, ignoring" event in Android

Tags: android, geolocation

I'm doing some GPS lookup in my android app. I've noticed that when I'm on a bad wifi network and don't have GSM available I see this funny log "onCellLocationChanged(): got cell location that isn't gsm, ignoring" and it doesn't hit my onLocationChange event

How can I capture this to kick off another provider (like network/etc)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is an old question, but I ended up finding this question while looking for how to capture this event. The documentation says about the [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html), and its [onCellLocationChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onCellLocationChanged%28android.telephony.CellLocation%29). For an example, check [here](http://enl.usc.edu/enl/trunk/aqua/test/CellInfoTest/src/aqua/example/cellinfotest/CellInfoTest.java) something more or less like this:

```
private final PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    public void onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation location) {
        /* here */
    }
    ...
};
```